# Does the Paypal user_id for a user ever change?

Tags: oauth, paypal

I am trying user PayPal OAuth login to authenticate users on my django system. I am getting a `user_id` back but it does not match the `user_id` that we got when the user previously logged in via PayPal. All the other details are the same so it is clearly the same account.

Has anyone else seen paypal `user_id` changing over time?

Comment: Are you referring to the client ID / secret generated by PayPal? When you logged into PayPal did you see the API username?

Comment: I am not logging into PayPal myself, it is my customers who are doing that. I am trying to use Paypal OAuth in the authentication backend for Django but the user_id returned by open_id isn't consistent over time.